# "for i" without "in [sequence]" ending while using getopt

Tags: bash, shell, getopt

I've found this example script for using getopt command in shell.

```
#!/bin/bash
args=$(getopt ab $*)
set -- $args
for i;
do
  case "$i" in
    -a)shift; echo "it was a";;
    -b)shift; echo "it was b";;
  esac;
done
```

It works well, but I don't understand where is variable $i assigned. How it knows that it must iterate through $arg. Can you explain this?

Comment: The `bash` man page can, under the description of the `for` loop.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As shown [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/loops1.html#EX23), `for` defaults to `$@` if no `in seq` is given. The `for i` assigns your `$i` variable.