# Pipe a list of strings to for loop

Tags: bash

How do I pass a list to `for` in bash?

I tried

```
echo "some
different
lines
" | for i ; do 
  echo do something with $i; 
done
```

but that doesn't work. I also tried to find an explanation with `man` but there is no `man for`

### EDIT:

I know, I could use `while` instead, but I think I once saw a solution with `for` where they didn't define the variable but could use it inside the loop

Comment: use a while read and redirect to your loop.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["for i" without "in \[sequence\]" ending while using getopt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16102089/for-i-without-in-sequence-ending-while-using-getopt)

Comment: Could you clarify your actual question? It has become unclear to me what you're asking.

Comment: I already added the answer below

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This might work but I don't recommend it:

```
echo "some
different
lines
" | for i in $(cat) ; do
    ...
done
```

`$(cat)` will expand everything on `stdin` but if one of the lines of the `echo` contains spaces, `for` will think that's two words. So it might eventually break.

If you want to process a list of words in a loop, this is better:

```
a=($(echo "some
different
lines
"))
for i in "${a[@]}"; do
    ...
done
```

Explanation: `a=(...)` declares an array. `$(cmd...)` expands to the output of the command. It's still vulnerable for white space but if you quote properly, this can be fixed.

`"${a[@]}"` expands to a correctly quoted list of elements in the array.

Note: `for` is a built-in command. Use `help for` (in bash) instead.

Comment: Thats great, and it is the shortest, and  if you wrote the string yourself in that loop you can just use `a="..."` and `for i in $a; do ...` if you know, that there are no "dangerous" signs in it

Comment: Actually, you should use `a=("word" "a b" "foo")` (3 elements) and then `for i in "${a[@]}"; do ...`; that would iterate three times. You would get 4 iterations.

Comment: But if you don't have spaces and special characters in those lines, you can simply use `$a` as in my example. (My intention is to lazy reformatting and piping stuff  on the console to get some things done)

Comment: That's not quite correct. Correct is: If you will never, ever, under no circumstances have spaces ... This is like no one will ever need more than 2 digits to save the year, an attitude which cost a lot of money in 1999.

Answer (score 27):

`for` iterates over a list of words, like this:

```
for i in word1 word2 word3; do echo "$i"; done
```

use a `while read` loop to iterate over lines:

```
echo "some
different
lines" | while read -r line; do echo "$line"; done
```

Here is [some useful reading](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) on reading lines in bash.

Comment: But i think I once saw a solution with `for` where they didn't define the variable but could use it inside the loop

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work :

```
for x in $(echo a b c); do
  echo $x
done
```

Comment: I know. It's an example ! You can also replace $(echo a b c) by $(my command printing some words). Thanks to remove your -1.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a pipe, but quite similar:

```
args="some
different
lines";
set -- $args; 
for i ; do 
  echo $i;
done
```

cause `for` defaults to `$@` if no `in seq` is given.

maybe you can shorten this a bit somehow?